# Breeze Js - Local query of "Lookup Lists"

Tags: javascript, breeze

In application for performance optimization we using bulk entities loading, like in "Lookup Lists" example http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/lookup-lists.
Query looks like this:

```
entityQuery.from('SomeBreezeAction')
   .using(manager)
   .execute()
   .then(function (res) {
  var set1 = res.results[0].first;
  var set2 = res.results[0].second;
}
```

It working very well remotely. Breeze correctly understand entity types of both entities and generate object based on metadata. In same application we using local Breeze queries for Jasmine tests of client side logic. But query like:

```
entityQuery.from('SomeBreezeAction')
   .using(manager)
   .executeLocally()
   .then(function (res) {
  var set1 = res.results[0].first;
  var set2 = res.results[0].second;
}
```

fails with error: Error: Cannot find an entityType for resourceName: 'SomeBreezeAction'. Consider adding an 'EntityQuery.toType' call to your query or calling the MetadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName method to register an entityType for this resourceName.

This is reasonable because we are not using toType or setEntityTypeForResourceName in this query. So my question is it possible to use toType or setEntityTypeForResourceName or something else for such queries which returns more than one entity type in one request?
If its important we define metadata manually and have not direct EF or other DB connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the client has no idea what "SomeBreezeAction" means. The logic for this operation is entirely contained on the server.

What you can do though is create your own function that performs the same queries locally that "SomeBreezeAction" does on the server and combines the results returned into the same 'shape' that your server side query does. This function can then be called whenever you want a local version of the same query.

Comment: Thanks for answer, so that means Breeze do not support some type of mapping between resource name and multiple entity types?